# Disable '%' character escaping

Tags: sqlalchemy, pymysql

In a certain context it would be useful to disable character escaping of a query string or at least disable specifically '%' character escaping.

Is such thing possible? How?

I know it is possible to escape that character with '%%' but I want to avoid doing that.

Simple query example:

```
SELECT '%2C'
```

Expected result:

```
'%2C'
```

I'm using sqlalchemy and pymysql.

Comment: when I run that in DBeaver using postgresql it returns one row with the string value `%2C`. What is your expected output? If you're looking to use a regex you might be able to use `REGEXP_MATCHES(source_string, pattern [, flags])`. Overall it's going to be hard to answer your question without some more context.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935854/how-to-escape-in-a-query-using-pythons-sqlalchemys-execute-and-pymysql

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley I've just updated my question with the expected result. I know the example seems dumb, because I'm presenting a very simplified example precisely targeting my intent. 

Comment: @IljaEverilä Maybe this will work in my use case... I'll test it! Initially was narrowing the question too much around pymysql... I'll give feedback later.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That's it! It totally solves my use case and feels like the right way to do it. I guess this must be marked as a duplicate of that other question. Thanks!